# How can I enable intellisense for Stride 3D in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, stride

I have installed Visual Studio and Stride 3D, but, when I'm using Visual Studio it doesn't help me with code recommendations. For example, if I write "Ent" it doesn't show me `Entity`, or, if I have more assets code it doesn't help me find that component.

How do I enable intellisense for Stride 3D in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see available to support this is [the official Visual Studio extension for Stride 3D:](https://doc.stride3d.net/4.0/en/manual/get-started/visual-studio-extension.html)

> The Stride Visual Studio extension adds syntax highlighting, live code validation, error checking, and navigation. It also lets you you edit shaders directly from Visual Studio.
>
> You don't need to install the extension to use Stride, but we recommend it, especially for programmers.

When you install Stride 3D, you're given the option to install the extension:

[image: Screenshot of the extension prompt from initial setup.]

If you elected not to install the extension on initial setup, you can install it from the launcher:

[image: Screenshot of the launcher.]

---

Unfortunately, for VS Code users, there doesn't seem to be an extension available.

Comment: I did install visual studio plugin there and it works to run it.